# Java ScheduledExecutorService with Hazelcast to execute tasks in weblogic cluster

Tags: java, weblogic, cluster-computing, hazelcast, scheduledexecutorservice

Requirement is
1. Pick up tasks from database and call web service for those tasks
2. Need to do this in Weblogic cluster where only single instance of scheduler/executor should run.

We have Hazelcast support so i am thinking of getting java ExecutorService from Hazelcast. This ExecutorService will "pick tasks from DB and execute web service call". So each node will have to go through this ExecutorService

Is this the right approach?

My main concern is for not make duplicate calls in the cluster

The reason i do not want to use Quartz scheduler is because i cannot store quartz scheduler in Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast didn't support a ScehduledExecutorService. There is an open issue for it [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/115).

I my opinion, you should use a queue : Put tasks on this queue, and on each node poll this queue. You'll be sure to invoke a task only once, and the work will be distributed. This kind of implementation is not fully fault-tolerant, though. If a node crash during the execution of a task, it will be lost.

Comment: Hazelcast provides a distributed ExecutorService. I want to wrap this object as a Runnable object and provide it to a ScheduledExecutorService to run at Scheduled time